# Expand label that all text can fit in ( UITableViewCell )

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableviewCell with 1 label, to expand it when clicking on it and to collopase it again when again clicking on it. Now my animation on how to expand the cell is like this:

```
    CGFloat targetHeightOfCell = [c.textLabel sizeOfMultiLineLabel].height;

    _expandedState.height = @(targetHeightOfCell);

    CGFloat difference = targetHeightOfCell - DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT;
    CGFloat targetHeightOfContent = self.tableView.contentSize.height + difference;


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
                         frame.size.height = targetHeightOfContent;
                         self.tableView.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
```

and in my heightForRowAtIndexPath I ofcourse return the right height. The cell expands but my calculation of sizeOfMultiLineLabel isn't correct. The text expands but still not all text is visible and so it's still appended by ...

This is my category on UILabel:

```
- (CGSize)sizeOfMultiLineLabel {

    NSAssert(self, @"UILabel was nil");

    //Label text
    NSString *aLabelTextString = [self text];

    //Label font
    UIFont *aLabelFont = [self font];

    //Width of the Label
    CGFloat aLabelSizeWidth = self.frame.size.width;


    //Return the calculated size of the Label
    CGSize size = [aLabelTextString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(aLabelSizeWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:@{
                                               NSFontAttributeName : aLabelFont
                                       }
                                          context:nil].size;

    //Check if the height isn't smaller then the default one
    if(size.height < DEFAULT_HEIGHT){
        return CGSizeMake(aLabelSizeWidth, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    } else {
        return size;
    }
}
```

What I want is that how long the text is, the label must expand so the user can see it.

Comment: you can use sizeToFit method to fit your whole text into label when you expand. and set frame to your default size when collapse.

Comment: No, even size to fit doesn't make the label big enough for all the text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your label has `numberOfLines` set correctly. If not, you probably want to set it to 0 to ensure that it can have as many lines as needed. You also need to ensure the wrapping mode is correct, e.g. `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`. Finally, depending on your cell layout there might be margins arount the label - so ensure you account for that when returning the height.

Comment: My line breaks mode is Word wrap and my numberOfLines is 0. My label has constraints to stick to every side so it fills the whole cell. Still the cell isn't big enough after calculation to show everything.

Comment: Ok, so no spacing in your layout? Do you have separators that could make the available content rect size height smaller? have you tried appending a few pixels to the estimated height to see the results?